# Can't dual boot on my Toshiba laptop

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my Toshiba Satellite C55-B5299. At first, GRUB was not booting at all. I used `boot-repair` to try to fix this. However, whenever I boot, I get this...

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

...then the computer boots into Windows, just as before. What should I do to remedy this? Thanks so much, as I am a noob.